# How can I convert SQL statements created using MySQL Workbench so it is compatible with Oracle

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, mysql-workbench

I have created an ERD on MySQL Workbench 6.0.8 CE and managed to export an automated SQL statement using the export option. How can I create a compatible SQL which can be used on Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle Database and MySQL are normally suited to different use cases. But, if you want to convert the SQL statements created using MySQL workbench to a compatible Oracle SQL Developer, you can do it via a simple operation: Migration. In this case, you will migrate the whole schema. (which is a more recommended solution)

SQL Developer is a free and fully supported product that provides tools and utilities to migrate from MySQL to Oracle. Check [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/connect-step-mysql-1946352.html).

If you get stuck on a step, please give me a sign. I'll be pleased to help.

Hope it's useful!